# How to interpret brms output for binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, bayesian, regression-coefficients, binary-data

So I have a binary response variable: $SP(0=\text{seronegative}, 1=\text{seropositive}, SP = \text{disease state})$ and I have just been playing around with my variables to understand what the output means. Here, I have so far, $Age (1=\text{Juvenile}, 2=\text{Sub Adult}, 3=\text{Adult})$ and $Sex (0=\text{Female}, 1=\text{Male})$ and I am slightly confused by the output as I don't see $Age\;1$ or $Female$? 
Are the results interpreted in this or how do I interpret this output?

Thanks for helping!

```
prior <- brms::prior(student_t(4,0,0.875), class = b)

m1 <- brms::brm(SP ~ AGECODE + SEXCODE, 
                   data = Ehel,
                   family = bernoulli(link = "logit"),
                   prior = prior,
                   seed = 1340
                   )
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The model here is something like

$$ SP(\text{agecode}, \text{sexcode} \sim Binomial(N, p(\text{agecode}, \text{sexcode})) $$

The linear predictor in your model looks something like
$$ \text{logit} (p) = \text{intercept} + \text{agecode}_i + \text{sexcode}_{j} $$

Where the agecode and sexcode are categorical factors. In these scenario with catageorical variables the coefficient for female and agecode1 will be *zero*, they are ``baseline'' categories. The coefficient for male is the average difference between a man and woman. The coefficient for agecode2 is the difference between a juvenile and sub adult, agecode3 is the difference between juvenile and an adult. 
So some concrete examples:

A juvenile female will have, $\text{logit}(p) = \text{intercept}$.

A juvenile male will have $\text{logit}(p) = \text{intercept} + \text{sexcode}_1$.

An adult male will have $\text{logit}(p) = \text{intercept} + \text{sexcode}_1 + \text{agecode}_3$.

Comment: That is a great explanation thank you!